# How to convert a single digit to a character in pure assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, type-conversion

What should happen is a digit in eax, such as 9, is converted to its character form, '9', and is outputted. I am using nasm on a 32-bit linux machine.

```
section .data
int: dw 9

section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 9
    add eax, 48
    mov ecx, [eax]

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, 1  
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

When running this program, I get a segmentation fault. I debug using gdb and I get a segmentation fault at the line where it says `mov ecx, [eax]`. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mov ecx, [eax]` means to interpret `eax` as a memory address, and copy the data at that location into `ecx`. This will try to dereference memory at 0x00000039, which is causing the crash.

Instead, if you want to copy the value in `eax` into `ecx`, use `mov ecx, eax` (without the square brackets).

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesn't work. I think it's because the syscall requires ecx to contain an address of a string.

Comment: You need to store the byte 0x39 (i.e., ASCII '9') in memory, and put the memory address in `ecx`. A standard way to do this is to allocate space on the stack (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames#Standard_Entry_Sequence) then `lea ecx, [ebp - 4]` (or similar) to get the address of your stack-allocated buffer.

Comment: ahh thank you very much. i replaced mov ecx, [eax] with push eax and then lea ecx, [esp] and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You correctly convert the number 9, stored in `eax`, to the ASCII codepoint for the character '9' by adding 48 to it, but then rather than storing that value in a buffer to call `write` with, you are treating it as a memory address and reading from that address into `ecx`.  Memory address (9 + 48 =) 57 is within the area of address space reserved to catch dereferences of the null pointer, so you get a segfault.

You want something like this instead (note: I refuse to use Intel's back-asswards syntax; compile with `gcc numbernine.s`; on a 64-bit distribution, you will need to use `gcc -m32 numbernine.s`):

```
        .data
        .align 4
        .type buf,@object
        .size buf, 2
buf:
        .byte 0
        .byte 10

        .text
        .align 4
        .globl main
        .type main,@function
main:
        leal buf,%ecx
        movb $9,%al
        addb $48,%al
        movb %al,(%ecx)

        subl $12,%esp
        movl $2,8(%esp)
        movl %ecx,4(%esp)
        movl $1,(%esp)
        call write
        addl $12,%esp

        xorl %eax,%eax
        ret
```

Tangential kibitz: Only make direct system calls if there is NO ALTERNATIVE.  If the C library provides a wrapper, use it.  It's less of a problem for `write`, but there are a whole bunch of system calls for which the C library wrapper is going to some length to insulate you from changes in the bare kernel ABI, and you don't want to have to know about that.  Also, the C library knows how to use `sysenter` (or `syscall` for the 64-bit ABI) and how to set `errno`.  This is why I am pushing stuff onto the stack and calling `write` rather than what you were doing.

Furthermore, it's silly to use a direct system call to terminate the process when you can just return from `main`.

Comment: +1 for the tangential remarks.
The code is bad, though, I doubt you tried to compile it yourself ;)

Comment: Fixed, thanks for pointing it out.  This is what I get for answering Linux questions from an OSX machine :)

Answer (score 0):

That means you're treating the value of `eax` as an address and looking it up in memory. Just remove the brackets.

Comment: when I remove the brackets and try running the program, nothing happens.